# Discord.js - How to move user to another channel

Tags: javascript, discord

Does anyone know how to move people with discord.js? Right now what I have is this:

```js
if (message.content === `${prefix}bring`){
 member.voice.setChannel('801285931868356658') 
}
```

Since the API is always changing I couldn't really find a way to do this.

Comment: So is it just silently not working or do you get an error ?

Comment: Do you receive any sort of error? Also, have you checked the channel id?

Comment: Also, what is the class type of `member`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the current `discord.js` documentation, I think you are on the right track. If we take a look at `VoiceState` Object (which you get from `member.voice`) it exposes the following method ([in the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=setChannel)):

### `setChannel( [channel], [reason] )`

In your example you are using a simple id (string) for the channel parameter. According to the docs, the channel parameter can either be of type `ChannelResolvable` or `null`. So I guess you need to actually pass the channel object rather than the id only.

This  is just from reading the docs.